# How to set class property dynamicly in python?

Tags: python, properties, setattr

I want to set class property dynamicly. I do it like this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1


for v in [1, 2, 3]:
    setattr(Foo, f"test_{v}", property(lambda self: self.a + v))

foo = Foo()
print(foo.test_1)
print(foo.test_2)
print(foo.test_3)
```

but I find that this will return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `setattr` is `setattr(object, name, value)`

```
class Foo:
    pass


for v in [1, 2, 3]:
    setattr(Foo, f"test_{v}", v)

foo = Foo()
print(foo.test_1)
print(foo.test_2)
print(foo.test_3)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

### Edit: 1

If becomes very easy if you set the property to the objects instead

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = a
        for v in [1, 2, 3]:
          setattr(self, f"test_{v}", self.a + v )

foo = Foo()
print(foo.test_1, foo.test_2, foo.test_3)
foo = Foo(10)
print(foo.test_1, foo.test_2, foo.test_3)
```

Output:

```
2 3 4
11 12 13
```

But, if you want to set it at class level, then answer by @nlair is closes.

Comment: maybe my example is too simple, I have edit the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the evaluation of `v`. You can use `partial` from `functools`. I am not sure it is very clean but it does what you are looking for.

```
from functools import partial

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1


for v in [1, 2, 3]:
    def aux(obj,x):
        return obj.a + x
    setattr(Foo, f"test_{v}", property(partial(aux,x=v))

foo = Foo()
print(foo.test_1)
print(foo.test_2)
print(foo.test_3)
```

Output:

```
2
3
4
```